# Приложение не работает с EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-core, entity-framework-core

При использовании EntityFramework приложение не запускается на чистой Windows 10.

1. Создал решение с двумя проэктами .net core 3.1
2. Во второе подключил EntityFrameworkCore, EntityFrameworkCore.Tools,
   EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
3. Сделал модель, DbContext, миграцию, вывод на экран таблицы
4. Опубликовал оба проэкта
5. Переместил на виртуальную машину
6. Установил на выделенную машину sdk + .net core Чистое wpf приложение
   запускается, с EntityFramework - запускается, появляется в процессах и пропадает, самого окнца даже не видно

В чем может быть прблема?

**P.S.** Даже если не делать модель, DbContext и миграцию - результат тот же.

Comment: Очевидные вещи - вылезла критическая ошибка, а с ошибками что помогает бороться? Правильно, отладка и логирование, вы это пробовали?

Comment: В правах проблема скорее всего, из какой папки запускаете и какому серверу цепляетесь?

Comment: [Проблема может быть в чём угодно](https://bash.im/quote/438821). Обкладывайтесь try..catch, логируйте. Придёте с логом - можно будет предметно поговорить, а пока вопрос стоит закрыть как неконкретный.